# Exist closed forms of the distribution of return time in markov chains?

Tags: markov-chains, probability-distributions, pr.probability

Hi, I am interested in the distribution of return times in simple random walks on finite graphs.

Let $G$ be a connected finite graph with, with two independent random walks. If both random walks start are at time $t_0$ on the same node in the graph, how long does it take until they meet again? I have not found papers on this specific problem, but read that is can be transformed to a single random walk and the question of when the random walk returns to exactly the node where it is at $t_0$.

As such I am interested in the distribution of these return times. Generally I know how to compute the numeric values of the distribution for a given graph. But my question is whether this can be modeled through a given distribution (e.g. exponential).

Besides the PDF I am more interested in the CDF of this return time distribution.

Comment: The first time when two independent random walks on $G$ both starting from $x_0$ with transition probabilities $p$ meet is the first return time to the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x);x\in G\}\subset G\times G$ by the random walk on $G\times G$ starting from $(x_0,x_0)$ whose transition probabilities $p_2$ are given by $p_2((x,y),(x',y'))=p(x,x')p(y,y')$.

Comment: More clarifications are needed: are we talking about simple random walks?

For a SRW on a regular graph the following is true: the probability of 2 independent SRW starting at the same vertex to be in the same place at some time $t$ is equal to the probability that a single SRW on the same graph returns to the starting vertex at time $2t$. But this does not say anything about the first time 2 SRWs meet.

Comment: @Ori: indeed, and more generally, for every random walk with uniform stationary measure.

Comment: @Didier: _reversible_ random walk with uniform stationary distribution.

Comment: @Ori: yes, reversible

Comment: @Ori: I am interested in a simple random walk. But the graph is not required to be regular. Does the relation of return time of a single random walker and that two random walkers starting at the same vertex meet still hold if the graph is not regular?


Comment: @Chris: the one line proof I know requires that $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$ for every $x$ and $y$ (which, if the random walk is simple, amounts to the fact that the degrees of the vertices are all equal). To see this, one decomposes $P_{(x,x)}[X_t=Y_t]$ as the sum over every possible $y$ of $P_{(x,x)}[X_t=Y_t=y]$ which is $P_x[X_t=y]P_x[Y_t=y]=p_t(x,y)^2=p_t(x,y)p_t(y,x)$ and one notices that the sum over $y$ of $p_t(x,y)p_t(y,x)$ is also the decomposition of $P_x[X_{2t}=x]$ along the possible values $y$ of $X_t$. 

Comment: For which graphs the distribution of the return time of the SRW to a given vertex is (shifted) geometric I do not know. But graphs for which this occurs are the complete graphs on $N$ vertices. For every starting vertex, the probability that the return time equals $1+t$ is $p(1-p)^{t-1}$ with $p=1/(N-1)$.

Comment: (cont'd) Another example is the discrete circle with $4$ vertices, for which the return times is twice a shifted geometric random variable with parameter $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the distribution of the time of first return, and I assume you're talking
about finite graphs.

I'll volunteer the naive answer:  let $M$ be the matrix of transition probabilities for your random walk, and let $M_i$ be the matrix obtained by modifyiong $M$ to make the $i$th column all 0's except for $1$ in the $(i,i)$ entry.  In other words, it's the matrix for a new random walk
that matches the old one, except whenever you get to $i$, you're trapped forever.

The CDF for first return from $j$ to $i$ is the sequence of $(i,j)$ entries of
$M_i^{n-1} \cdot M$: you start off with $M$, and afterward use $M_i$, and see if you've gotten
from $j$ to $i$.

If you transform $M_i$ into Jordan canonical form, there is a closed formula for
all its powers $\cdot M$; the $(i,j)$ entry is a linear functional on those powers.

If you want numerical answers for not-too-huge graphs, this should be easily workable. If
you want answers for a totally general directed graph with weighted edges, this corresponds
to a totally general matrix $M$, and it's unreasonable to expect any better answer. If
you have in mind some particular class of graphs with nice properties and nice random walks, then a lot more can be said, but I'm not an expert so I won't plunge in: perhaps some experts will say something about what's known.

Comment: Bill, thanks for clarification. I have overworked the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The question you ask is pretty broad, and it's not clear to me what kind of answers you seek.
In fact, I suggest you clean up the question a little bit (for example, what does "the return times for every pair in the graph." mean?).

I'm not sure whether this is relevant, but Asaf Nachmias and I have a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1438) on some properties of the distribution of the first time a simple random walk returns to its starting point on an infinite graph. The results can also be adapted, to some extent, to finite graphs.

Comment: Thanks Ori, the paper you mention goes into an interesting direction. I am looking to determine such a return time distribution for a given graph.
